# My Drop Down Menu and the sub-menu is not getting placed correctly in the browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I created an asp.net application called NetWeight, my dropdown menu and its sub menu is not correctly placed, some of them are place correctly while others co-inside with each other.

I have create a fiddle of my situation please help me out:

http://jsfiddle.net/debatechamp/nv93vahq/

as you can see if you hover over the MasterData tab all the menu's are neatly organized but the tab next to it, the product weight datasheet's print one item and print all item's submenu coincide with each other i am not even able to over over the items without the blocks interrupting each other.

Here is the CSS

```
/* DropDown Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {background-image: none; display:block;height: 28px; line-height: 26px; color:#381B01; width:142px; text-align:left; margin: 0; padding:0 0 0 11px;font-weight:normal;}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    padding: 0;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/cAxTTkk.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left; 
}

/* DropDown Menus ":active" or "Selected" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul .sub_active {
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/Npx66xl.png');
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/* DropDown Menus ":hover" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {color:#381B01 !important; background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/TwDd5GH.png');}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {display:block; position:absolute; left:105px; top:0;}
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.left {left:-105px;}

.wrap{
position:relative;
top:32px;
left:-10px;
float:left;
width:1647px;
height:829px;
background:#3A1C01 url('images/presentation/caramel-cream.png') no-repeat center 120px;
border:3px solid #f0f0f0;
padding-left:10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display:block


}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-left-color:#fff;
    margin-left: 10px;



}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: 180px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;

}
```

**The Html Code**

```
<ul>
                    <li class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a tabindex = "-1" >Print One Item</a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-submenu">
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintOneBag.aspx" >Bag</a></li>
                     <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintOneBar.aspx">Bar</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintOneSapal.aspx">Sapal</a></li>
                       <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintOneHandPack.aspx">Hand Pack</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a tabindex = "-1">Print All Items</a>
                    <ul class = "dropdown-submenu">
                    <li><a tabindex = "-1"   href = "AllBag.aspx">Bag</a></li>
                     <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "AllBar.aspx">Bar</a></li>
                      <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintAllSapal.aspx">Sapal</a></li>
                       <li><a tabindex = "-1" href = "PrintAllHandPack.aspx">Hand Pack</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

**Thanks For any help in advance, your help is much appreciated since i am not that good at css/html**

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Your fiddle looks fine. The two menu items "PrintOneItem" and "PrintAllItems" seem stacked just like the first list. am I missing out something?

Comment: @stripathi if look at their sub-menu box with print one bag, print one bar and then for the print all drop-down menu you have all bag, all bar, if i hover over from print one down to print one bar it automatically goes to all bag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite lots of updates in the CSS, and I can't list all the changes that I made. And I believe this is the best I can do. Obviously this background image isn't long enough https://i.stack.imgur.com/asng0.png You'll have to make a new one. You need 3 pieces, left + middle (repeat) + right, if you want to make it flexible.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nv93vahq/5/

```
body {
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/zh97eNW.jpg');
}

.pickit {
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #D8BC91;
    margin: 1px 8px 0 0;
    clear: none;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
/* --- Navbar Style --- */
#nav {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 36px;
    float: left;
    background: transparent;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
/* -- Brown Menu -- */
.menu {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, san-serif;
    width: 997px;
    height: 33px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: -1px;
    left: 1px;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #EBE0D5;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 181px;
    height: 42px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-image: url('images/brown/center.png');
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
/* End Caps Styling */
.menu .left_nosub {
    background-image: url('images/brown/left.png');
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
}

.menu .right_hassub {
    background-image: url('images/brown/right.png');
}

.menu .right_nosub {
    background-image: url('images/brown/right.png');
}

.menu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 1100px;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 3px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 179px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #D2C6AC;
}

.menu ul li ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.menu ul li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Button ":hover" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover a {
    color: #381B01;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/asng0.png') center top no-repeat;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    left: 0;
    width: 152px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li a.center_hassub {
    background: #6a3;
    color: #EBE0D5;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover a.center_hassub {
    background: #6fc;
    color: #381B01;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

.menu ul li:hover .left_nosub {
    color: #381B01;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/qr5mzZU.png');
}

.menu ul li:hover .right_hassub {
    color: #381B01;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/BdV64of.png');
}

.menu ul li:hover .right_nosub {
    color: #381B01;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/0vEO0KC.png');
}
/* DropDown Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    background-image: none;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #381B01;
    width: 126px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 13px;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0 0 15px;
    width: 152px;
}
/* DropDown Menus ":active" or "Selected" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul .sub_active {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Npx66xl.png');
    margin-right: 1px;
}
/* DropDown Menus ":hover" Styling */
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    color: #381B01 !important;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/TwDd5GH.png');
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 139px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.left {
    left: -105px;
}

.wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 32px;
    left: -10px;
    float: left;
    width: 1647px;
    height: 829px;
    background: #3A1C01 url('images/presentation/caramel-cream.png') no-repeat center 120px;
    border: 3px solid #f0f0f0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-left-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: green;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: 180px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
/* -- End Brown Menu -- */
```

*( I won't be surprised if this is the only answer :P I love debugging code! )*

Comment: looks way better than before but the print one item and print all item their sub-menus are still intersecting with each other, it there a way to make the block that the submenu is in to start from then end of the drop-down menu? thanks for the detailed response :)

Comment: Love it.....just what i wanted hopefully one day i can say this of myself (I love debugging code! ) i was looking at some youtube videos, w3shools and such but at the end of the day i believe to make it look like right you have to play with the number eh :) i know i already said thanks but thanks agian, i had my application all set to role out but the menu was bugging the crap out of me :)